# Move an MS Access query into a VB6 query that uses the first

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I have two tables, one table called *Act_Reg* and the other is *Active_Pay*. I have two queries: one query is a view in MS Access and it gives me the result as *Paycoach* :

```
SELECT Act_Reg.member_id, Active_Pay.date_pay, Active_Pay.kind_sport, 
       Active_Pay.kind_prac, Active_Pay.coach, Active_Pay.tuition, Active_Pay.discount
FROM   Act_Reg 
INNER JOIN Active_Pay ON Act_Reg.member_id = Active_Pay.member_id;
```

The second query I use in VB6 for getting the result of query one:

```
rstemp1.Open "SELECT sum(tuition)-sum(discount) FROM paycoach where date_pay Between '" & Trim(txtdatein.text) & "' And '" & Trim(txtdateto.text) & "' and coach='" & Cbocoach.text & "' and kind_sport='" & cbosport.text & "' and kind_prac='normal' group by tuition", db, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

I want to calculate the payment for each coach, according to paid membership and discount in a date range. The two queries work well, but one query is in MS Access as view and the second is in VB6.

How can I combine these two queries into one query, which I can use in Visual Basic 6?

Comment: Not sure I understand  - re you trying to move your Access query into VB6? And then use that combined SQL in your Open statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do just what you ask by doing exactly how you describe it.
It's probably not the most efficient, but this should work by simply inserting your Access query SQL directly into your VB6 query SQL

> **your paycheck query SQL**

```
SELECT Act_Reg.member_id, Active_Pay.date_pay, Active_Pay.kind_sport, 
       Active_Pay.kind_prac, Active_Pay.coach, Active_Pay.tuition, Active_Pay.discount
FROM   Act_Reg 
INNER JOIN Active_Pay ON Act_Reg.member_id = Active_Pay.member_id;
```

> **Your rs.Open sql**

```
"SELECT sum(tuition)-sum(discount) FROM paycoach where date_pay Between '" & _
Trim(txtdatein.text) & "' And '" & Trim(txtdateto.text) & "' and coach='" & _
Cbocoach.text & "' and kind_sport='" & cbosport.text & "' and kind_prac='normal' group by tuition"
```

> **Modify your rs.open to use Combined statement**

```
Dim sql as string

sql = "SELECT sum(tuition)-sum(discount) FROM "
sql = sql & "(SELECT Act_Reg.member_id, Active_Pay.date_pay, Active_Pay.kind_sport, "
sql = sql & "Active_Pay.kind_prac, Active_Pay.coach, Active_Pay.tuition, Active_Pay.discount "
sql = sql & "FROM Act_Reg INNER JOIN Active_Pay ON Act_Reg.member_id = Active_Pay.member_id) "
sql = sql & "As paycoach "
sql = sql & "where date_pay Between '"
sql = sql & Trim(txtdatein.text) & "' And '" & Trim(txtdateto.text) & "' and coach='"
sql = sql & Cbocoach.text & "' and kind_sport='" & cbosport.text & "' and kind_prac='normal' group by tuition"

rstemp1.Open sql, db, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Dear @dbmitch, sorry for my poor english. i used your code : `code Dim sql as string sql = "SELECT sum(tuition)-sum(discount) FROM " sql = sql & "(SELECT Act_Reg.member_id, Active_Pay.date_pay, Active_Pay.kind_sport, " sql = sql & "Active_Pay.kind_prac, Active_Pay.coach, Active_Pay.tuition, Active_Pay.discount " sql = sql & "FROM Act_Reg INNER JOIN Active_Pay ON Act_Reg.member_id = Active_Pay.member_id) " sql = sql & "As paycoach " sql = sql & "where date_pay Between '" sql = sql & Trim(txtdatein.text) & "' And '" & Trim(txtdateto.text) & "' and coach='" and ...... ` it turns nothing !!?

Comment: Dear @dbmitch, your code works good, it's my fault in my code. thanks again

Comment: Glad you perserved.